# Is there a way to make an icon in PowerApps have a hovering property much like in HTML?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm working on a website where I'm attempting to make an icon in PowerApps, have a property where the user can hold their mouse over the icon and have it display information about the text next to it. I'm not too knowledgeable in JavaScript or JSON for that matter, but this has simply gotten the best of me.

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Comment: I believe I should be able to do it based on what you posted, if all else fails I know an easy cop-out solution, thanks.

Comment: ok cool, you can upvote/accept the helpful answer to help others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tooltip property of the icon control - and that will give you exactly what you need

[image]

Comment: I was thinking more like aI box that wikipedia provides. Is that possible? When you hover over the text it gives you some information and a link or two.

Comment: In this case this is not currently supported for the existing icon control; you can consider creating a new feature request in the Ideas board at https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas

Answer (score 0):

Canvas PowerApps is mainly meant for mobile/tablet, though it can be accessed in desktop browser, the tooltip when mouse hover is impossible in mobile touch screens.

That being said, what you are looking for may align with custom tool tip or context menu - take a look at [this idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Tooltip-customization/idi-p/82896) and comments there.

The best bet would be your own custom component (PCF control) developed for this purpose.